# How to compile .sln with cmd.exe

Tags: visual-studio-2008, compilation, cmd

I tried to compile a .sln at windows cmd.exe with the following code:

```
C:\absolutePath\devenv.com /Build /ProjectConfig "Release|Win32"
```

I get following error message:

> Missing switch argument. Configuration name required for /Build switch.

However, this works:

```
C:\absolutePath\devenv.com /Build Release /ProjectConfig "Release|Win32"
```

But I want to use ProjectConfig because I have different Solution Configurations... So I also want to use this:

```
C:\absolutePath\devenv.com /Build /ProjectConfig "Release_OtherSolConf|Win32"
```

and this:

```
C:\absolutePath\devenv.com /Build /ProjectConfig "Release|x64"
```

When I make "/Build Release" does it overwrite "Release_OtherSolConf|Win32" ? I'm even confused why I have to give "/Build" the "Release" switch parameter. The "Release" is involved in the /ProjectConfig...
Can anybody please tell me how the command should look like? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

nvm, I'm sorry.
I think this is what I'm looking for:

```
C:\absolutePath\devenv.com file.sln /Build "Release|Win32"
```